# repository.liveData.value returns null when resume the app after sometimes

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I am loading contacts in Repository layer in my SplashActivity :

```
@Inject
lateinit var repository: ContactsRepository

private fun startMainActivity() {
        repository.loadContacts()
        handler.postDelayed({
            val intent =Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }, SPLASH_DELAY.toLong())
    }
```

And here is my Repository :

```
@Singleton
class ContactsRepository @Inject constructor(
        private val context: Context,
        private val schedulerProvider: BaseSchedulerProvider) {

    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    private val _liveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<Contact>>>()
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<List<Contact>>>
        get() = _liveData

    fun loadContacts() {
        _liveData.value = Resource.Loading()
        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION,
                null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE UNICODE ASC")
        Observable.create(ObservableOnSubscribe<List<Contact>>
        { emitter -> emitter.onNext(ContactUtil.getContacts(cursor, context)) })
                .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
                .doOnComplete { cursor?.close() }
                .doFinally { compositeDisposable.clear() }
                .subscribe {
                    _liveData.postValue(Resource.Success(it))
                }.also { compositeDisposable.add(it) }
    }
}
```

In my ContactsFragment I initialize my ViewModel :

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView()");
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
        ContactsViewModel viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, mFactory).get(ContactsViewModel.class);
        FragmentContactsBinding binding = FragmentContactsBinding.bind(root);
        binding.setVariable(BR.vm, viewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner());

            // Create the observer which updates the UI.
            final Observer<Resource<List<Contact>>> contactsObserver = resource -> {
                if (resource instanceof Resource.Success) {
                    mContacts = ((Resource.Success<List<Contact>>) resource).getData();
                    mAdapter.setItems(mContacts, true);
                }
            };
            // Observe the LiveData, passing in this fragment as the LifecycleOwner and the observer.
            viewModel.getLiveData().observe(this, contactsObserver);
}
```

And here is my ViewModel :

```
class ContactsViewModel(repository: ContactsRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _liveData = repository.liveData
    val liveData: LiveData<Resource<List<Contact>>>
        get() = _liveData

    init {
        if(repository.liveData.value == null) {
            repository.loadContacts()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Factory for constructing ContactsViewModel with parameter
     */
    class Factory @Inject constructor(
            private val repository: ContactsRepository
    ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ContactsViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return ContactsViewModel(repository) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to construct viewmodel")
        }
    }
}
```

As you see sometimes when I resume the app after a long time 'repository.liveData.value' returns null as a result I have following logic in ViewModel:

```
init {
        if(repository.liveData.value == null) {
            repository.loadContacts()
        }
    }
```

Is there any better solution ?

Full source code can be found : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/Contacts

Answer (score 1):

I think this can happen because the system GC'ed your application. This may occure when device is running out of memory. ViewModel will only survive configuration changes, not application death. To fix this you need to call `loadContacts` in `ContactsFragment#onCreateView` when `savedInstanceState != null`.

Comment: This means every time when I rotate the device, loadContacts will be called. My current solution does not have this issue when I rotate the device : mContacts = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(CONTACTS);

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Than you can do lazy initialization of this value if it's null

Answer (score 1):

ViewModels don't survive system-initiated process death. To deal with this, you need to use a SavedStateHandle:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/SavedStateHandle

For example, in `FilterViewModel` in the link below I use a SavedStateHandle to store a set of indices and retrieve them if SavedStateHandle is not null (it'll only be non-null in the case of system initiated process death):

https://github.com/gavingt/upcoming-games/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gavinsappcreations/upcominggames/ui/filter/FilterViewModel.kt

Comment: In my case type of LiveData is <Resource<List<Contact>> which is not Parcelable in order to save in SavedStateHandle, but I agree that it works when type is different.